# How to use a function in MIPS

Tags: mips

I am just starting out with MIPS and was confused with the calling of functions from main in MIPS like how to send parameters and get the returning value from the function. A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code to understand how to implement functions in MIPS. Here we are just using a function to calculate the sum of three values.

```
.data
A: .word 2
B: .word 3
C: .word 9
Answer: .word 0
 
.text
.globl main

main:

#These are basically the parameters
lw $a0, A   #Load value from memory location A into the register $a0
lw $a1, B   #Load value from memory location B into the register $a1
lw $a2, C   #Load value from memory location C into the register $a2

jal Sum     #Calling the function

sw $v0, Answer  #Storing the contents of $v0 into the memory location Answer(The returning value)

li $v0, 10
syscall
.end main

.globl Sum      #Function for Sum
.ent Sum

Sum:

add $v0, $a0, $a1
add $v0, $v0, $a2

jr $ra
.end Sum
```

You can follow the comments and can see how the function is used. Here are some important points to note:
Combination of registers and stack is used for argument transition. Integer arguments are passed using the registers $a0, $a1, $a2, $a3 and floating point values can be passed using $f12 and $f14. The first argument should either be passed in $a0 or $f12 depending on whether the argument is integer or floating point. Similarly the second argument should either be passed in $a1 or $f14. The third argument has to be passed in $a2 for integer and if the third argument is float then it has to be passed on the stack. Similarly the fourth argument has to be passed on $a3 and if the fourth argument is float then it has to be passed on the stack. Any additional arguments are passed on the stack.
Integer registers $v0/$v1 are used to return an integer value from a function call and floating point registers $f0 and $f1 are used to return a floating point value from the function.
The call to a function is as follows:
jal FunctionName,
whereas the return from function is as follows:
jr $ra.
You can also use the book mentioned below as a guide to learning MIPS using software called QTSpim, it might help you with any other confusions.
MIPS Assembly Language Programming using QtSpim Ed Jorgensen, Ph.D. Version 1.1.50 July 2019.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

- Sending parameters to a function:
  Use either $a0 or $f12 ($a0 if integer or $f12 if float single or double precision) to pass the first parameter.
  Use either $a1 or $f14 ($a1 if integer or $f14 if float single or double precision) to pass the second parameter.
  Use $a2 to pass the third parameter(integer only). If the third parameter is float, it must be passed on the stack.
  Use $a3 to pass the forth parameter(integer only) but If the forth parameter is float, then it must be passed on the stack.

Keep in mind: If the first parameter is integer, $a0 is used and $f12 is then not used. And if the first parameter is floating-point value, $f12 is used and $a0 is not used at all. Any additional parameters are passed on the stack.

move the contents of temporary registers which are to be passed as parameters to a function in accordance to the above points before calling the function using jump commands.

- returning values from a function:

Integer registers $v0 or $v1/$v0 are used to return an integer value from a
function. Floating-point registers $f0 and $f1 are used to return a
floating-point value from a function.

Answer (score 1):

**Function initialization:**

```
.globl functionName
.ent functionName

functionName:

#Code here

.end functionName
```

**Calling conventions:**

*- Arguments:*
◦ The first argument is passed in either **$a0** or **$f12** ($a0 if integer or $f12 if
float single or double precision).
◦ The second argument is passed in either **$a1** or **$f14** ($a1 if integer or $f14 if
float single or double precision).
◦ The third argument is passed in **$a2** (integer only).
◦ If the third argument is float, it must be passed on the stack.
◦ The fourth argument is passed in **$a3** (integer only).
◦ If the fourth argument is float, it must be passed on the stack.

Remaining arguments are passed on the stack. Arguments on the stack should be placed
on the stack in reverse order. Call-by-reference arguments load address (la instruction)
and call-by-value load the value.

**Calling a function:**
In order to call a function from main, you'll use `jal functionName`

**Returning a function:**
In order to return to the main function, you'll use `jr $ra`

**Function Result:**
Integer registers **$v0** or **$v1/$v0** are used to return an integer value from a
function/procedure call. Floating-point registers **$f0** and **$f1** are used to return a
floating-point value from a function/procedure.

**Registers Preservation Conventions:**
The MIPS calling convention requires that only specific registers (not all) be saved
across procedure calls.
• Integer registers **$s0 - $s7** must be saved by the procedure.
• Floating-point registers **$f20 - $f30** must be saved by the procedure.